# Apache maven wagon provider exception

Tags: maven, wagon

I have created new maven project and tried to reload maven project by adding dependencies in pom.xml.

But I'm getting below error
Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpwagon$__sisu21

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: just also add `pom.xml` file to have more details.

Comment: Also more details which Maven version etc. JDK you are using?